# How many triples in a document?

Tags: rdf, marklogic

I am using MarkLogic's recent RDF facility.  All the load methods I can find split my input into documents of 100 triples.  Is there any way to configure this to a different size?

Answer (score 2):

No such option exists as of 7.0-3. What is your reason for wanting to configure the value?

You can certainly create and manage your own documents containing the triple data if wish.

Comment: I am trying to tune the usage of the documents.  I want the organization in MarkLogic to mirror the organization in the file system (i.e., if I update a file, I want to know what docs to update in ML).  The obvious way would be for the docs in ML and the docs in the file system to be 1-1.   That might not be sensible, but I wanted to play with it.

Comment: Also, I am surprised that neither of you pointed me to  semi:itpd($n), which configures this parameter.   I found that by digging through the XQuery code (I keep forgetting how much of ML is available by looking at the Modules code in xquery).

Comment: Maybe not the best idea to use an undocumented function. There's a good reason for multiple triples per document. Triples are very small, and documents have on-disk and in-memory overhead. You might find yourself using, say, 1-kB of disk space per triple with 1:1, vs 5-kB per 100 triples with 1:100.